# Using if/else statements and the functions lower()/isalpha() and upper() to print all the words that starts with "h" and higher?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
quote="Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart"
word=""
for character in quote:
    if character.lower().isalpha()==True:
        word+=character.lower()
    else:
        if word[0]>="h":
            print(word.upper())
            word=""
        else:
            word = ""
```

I´m getting only the two first words printed and then:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dubir/PycharmProjects/Läraprogrammering/Dubirka2.py", line 153, in 
    if word[0]>="h":
IndexError: string index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: A question is not simply a dump of code... Add details about what is not working, what error you get, and what the code is supposed to do...

Comment: It only prints out the first two words and then : if word[0]>="h":
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Please rewrite your post: shorten the title; include your actual question in the post; paste a complete error message, if any.

Comment: Just as a side note, the objective in your title can be done in one line: `[print(word.upper()) for word in quote.split() if word[0]>='h']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two major problems:

1. if the last characters is an alpha one, then it will never get printed, since after that word, you will never enter the `else` case;
2. it is possible that `word` still has length `0`, since there can be two non-alpha's in row. For instance `', '`.

You can fix the code itself by using:

```
word=""
for character in quote:
    if character.isalpha():
        word += character.lower()
    else:
        if word and word[0] >= "h":
            print(word.upper())
        word=""
if word and word[0] >= "h":
    print(word.upper())
```

But this is still is not very declarative. A better approach is probably:

```
import re

rgx = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z]+')

for word in rgx.split(quote):
    if word and word[0] >= 'h':
        print(word.upper())
```

we can make it a bit more elegant by using the slicing operator and thus reduce the *number* of checks:

```
import re

rgx = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z]+')

for word in rgx.split(quote):
    if word[:1] >= 'h':
        print(word.upper())
```

Comment: You have a good point there.. I missed that totally. I´m still a newbie.. taking a introduction course and this assignment should be solved with only these steps. No complex code should be needed :) thanks for the answer! Helped a lot!